# Renamed item and now not displaying child pages

Tags: content-editor, publishing

What would cause content not to load if we rename the parent page? We have various categories of content on our homepage that all get pulled in. We had to change the name (and display name) of some of the parent pages and now nothing will feed to these areas.

I've check the item name and path it all matches and reflects the new name.

I'm new to sitecore and we don't have internal web support so I'm on my own. Any ideas, where to look, etc. would be helpful.

[![content editor][1]][1][![front page example][2]][2]
[image: content details][image: content]

Comment: Hi Jessi, Can you share some screenshots of the behavior that you're seeing, and if we can peek at the content editor to see what you're seeing.. That would help us help you.  :)

Comment: Can you share the code that is rendering that area of your homepage? Btw, first check if someone did not hard-code a path there ;)  (and **** them if they did)

Comment: not sure if that's exactly what you're looking for... As far as the code, I don't see anything hardcoded, but I'm only looking at the page source.

Comment: Are you looking on the published site or in preview? Is there a difference? Can you make sure that everything is published correctly?

Comment: Did you publish the changes? Are you using the Content Search API, and if so have the indexes been rebuilt?

Comment: This happens when I publish as well. I've done smart publish and republish.

Comment: The only thing that seems to keep the content is if I don't change the item name but change the display name only. Of course, the url reflects the old name but everything works and is pulled in.

Comment: When you published, was Publish sub-items checked? Its a basic question, but since you said you're new to Sitecore I figured I'd ask.

Comment: Have you tried to navigate to the new pages? If so, what happens? Can you also add the following additional screenshot(s), please: go to the Presentation tab -> Details -> Edit (under Default) -> Controls -> click the rendering that displays the category content -> click Edit -> take screenshot -> (repeat for additional renderings, as needed).

Comment: Possibly the datasource of the component has the item path in it rather than a GUID hence it working still display name is changed... Try switching on `Raw Values` from the View ribbon in Content Editor and then checking the datasource field of the component from Presentation Details.

Comment: FYI - you can use the instructions in my comment to take a screenshot of the Datasource field of the rendering, that @jammykam mentions. Before following the steps that I outlined, be sure to go to View -> and check Raw Values

Comment: Chris, yes sub-items are checked. Thanks @ZacharyKniebel I've taken the screenshots with the Raw Values switched on. Added them to the original post.

Comment: Not sure that we can see them right now, Jessi. Are you sure you added them to this post?

Comment: Sorry was in a meeting. I'm only able to upload 2 images, but the other renderings look exactly the same as the one I posted. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it!

Comment: You may want to obfuscate the client's name in your screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Not that this is the correct answer but it did solve my problem. I clicked "never publish" on the parent item. Saved. Then unchecked "never publish", saved and selected Republish item and bam, everything showed up on the homepage with correct item name and display name.

I'm not sure why it works, but it does. Thank you all for your help. 
Sincerely,
Jessi[image: fake story]

Comment: The reason might be that at the time the error was happening, the cache has not been cleared properly. Your live site was still serving the previous item name. Normally, sitecore cache gets cleared when publishing occurs or when the app pool restart. You may try to clear the cache manually from the cache.aspx page next time you have this issue and see if it resolve the problem

Comment: @HishaamNamooya where would I find that page? thanks.

Comment: The link is [yourDomain]/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx